# git: show all changed files between two commits but keep A|M|D

Tags: git

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only
```

This shows me the list of files changed in HEAD, say:

```
pkg.file1.java
pkg.file2.java
pkg.file3.java
```

What I want is to retain whether the file was added, modified, or deleted:

```
M pkg.file1.java
D pkg.file2.java
A pkg.file3.java
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-status
```

Comment: FYI: got this from using options from `git ls-tree --help` on `git-show`.